# text-left !important not working inside buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I do have some input buttons using bootstrap, the trouble I have is that even if on the .text-left class I added !important, it's not working on buttons.

How can we fix this ?

```css
.text-left {
    text-align: left !important;
}



.btn {
    box-shadow: none;
    border-radius: 0;
}
.w100 {
    width: 100%;
}
.btn-default {
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #ccc;
}
.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
a {
    color: #72c02c;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a {
    color: #337ab7;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://www.sp-batiment.com/assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div> <div class="text-left"> <a href="blog/immobilier.html"> <btn class=" btn btn-default w100 "><i class="fa fa-building-o "></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Immobilier (4)</strong></btn> </a> <a href="blog/entretien.html"> <btn class=" btn btn-default w100 "><i class="fa fa-wrench "></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Entretien (2)</strong></btn> </a> <a href="blog/tendances-deco.html"> <btn class=" btn btn-default w100 "><i class="fa fa-file-image-o "></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Tendances déco (9)</strong></btn> </a> <a href="blog/actualite.html"> <btn class=" btn btn-default w100 "><i class="fa fa-file-text-o "></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Actualité (7)</strong></btn> </a> <a href="blog/technologies.html"> <btn class=" btn btn-default w100 "><i class="fa fa-cogs "></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Technologies (5)</strong></btn> </a> <a href="blog/renovations.html"> <btn class=" btn btn-default w100 "><i class="fa fa-hotel "></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Rénovations (12)</strong></btn> </a> <a href="blog/divers.html"> <btn class=" btn btn-default w100 "><i class="fa fa-puzzle-piece "></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Divers (7)</strong></btn> </a> <a href="blog/videos-renovations.html"> <btn class=" btn btn-default w100 "><i class="fa fa-film "></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Vidéos de rénovations (3)</strong></btn> </a> <a href="blog/ameliorations-energetiques.html"> <btn class=" btn btn-default w100 "><i class="fa fa-calculator "></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Améliorations énergétiques (3)</strong></btn> </a> </div> </div>
```

I know this thread has been seen few times, but I did not find any real response.

Comment: you want to align the text of the buttons to the left or the button itself?

Comment: the text inside

Comment: the `btn` class has `text-align: center;` which is winning in the cascade

Comment: but why is it not working with the class !important ?

Comment: because you center the text of the `div.text-left` not the buttons. Thats why you need to change your selector like in my anwser below: `.text-left btn { text-align: left; }`

Comment: (Quick helpful steer on English: [anykind](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a1323716%20anykind) is always two words: "any kind". However it is also worth pointing out that notes on appreciation tend to be removed here, since they are not technical writing.)

Comment: `<btn>` is invalid HTML, there is no `<btn>` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for `!important` -> just use `.text-left btn {` as selector.

```css
.text-left btn {
    text-align: left;
}



.btn {
    box-shadow: none;
    border-radius: 0;
}
.w100 {
    width: 100%;
}
.btn-default {
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #ccc;
}
.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
a {
    color: #72c02c;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a {
    color: #337ab7;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://www.sp-batiment.com/assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div> <div class="text-left"> <a href="blog/immobilier.html"> <btn class=" btn btn-default w100 "><i class="fa fa-building-o "></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Immobilier (4)</strong></btn> </a> <a href="blog/entretien.html"> <btn class=" btn btn-default w100 "><i class="fa fa-wrench "></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Entretien (2)</strong></btn> </a> <a href="blog/tendances-deco.html"> <btn class=" btn btn-default w100 "><i class="fa fa-file-image-o "></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Tendances déco (9)</strong></btn> </a> <a href="blog/actualite.html"> <btn class=" btn btn-default w100 "><i class="fa fa-file-text-o "></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Actualité (7)</strong></btn> </a> <a href="blog/technologies.html"> <btn class=" btn btn-default w100 "><i class="fa fa-cogs "></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Technologies (5)</strong></btn> </a> <a href="blog/renovations.html"> <btn class=" btn btn-default w100 "><i class="fa fa-hotel "></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Rénovations (12)</strong></btn> </a> <a href="blog/divers.html"> <btn class=" btn btn-default w100 "><i class="fa fa-puzzle-piece "></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Divers (7)</strong></btn> </a> <a href="blog/videos-renovations.html"> <btn class=" btn btn-default w100 "><i class="fa fa-film "></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Vidéos de rénovations (3)</strong></btn> </a> <a href="blog/ameliorations-energetiques.html"> <btn class=" btn btn-default w100 "><i class="fa fa-calculator "></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Améliorations énergétiques (3)</strong></btn> </a> </div> </div>
```

Comment: thank you Sir, I was searching for this for a long time, I did not know it was so evident

Comment: `<btn>` is invalid HTML, there is no `<btn>` element.

Comment: @connexo I know. It was justt he original code from the OP. I just assume that it was a library he sues.